# When building forms in Django, is it good practice to use one 'fat' model to contain all my fields for multiple forms?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-forms

**Context:**
I am building a car dealership app and have multiple forms to create such as:
A basic contact requesting a name, email, phone and comments.
A service form requesting the above along with the users make, model and mileage
A sales form, requesting all the above again along with a few other similarly relevant questions.

**Problem:** So I'm trying to find out is it best practice to have one 'fat' model containing all these fields and then create multiple forms from them or to create a model per form?

I know that I should stick to the DRY practices but I would really benefit from a stronger understanding.

Comment: Please don't think in terms of forms. You should design models to focus on how to *store* data, that is the entire point of separating these from forms.

Comment: It is not good practice to make one model if there is a one-to-many, or many-to-many relation. For example multiple car's have the same make, so then you construct a `Make` model, and the `CarType` has a `ForeignKey` to that `Make`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Thank you very much for your input! I'll follow that advice :)